# procedural php and sql login script not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I cannot login to my web application which is currently running on my local server. Please help, below is the PHP script...Your help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
   <?php
    session_start();

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
       include 'db.inc.php';

      //Escape special characters/
      $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
      $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

      $login = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$email'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $login);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      if ($resultCheck < 1) {
      header('Location: ../register.php?login=error-zero');
    }  else {
     if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $hashedpwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
       if ($hashedpwdCheck == false) {
           header('Location: ../register.php?login=error'); //IT STOPS RUNNING HERE
           exit();
       } elseif ($hashedpwdCheck == true){
               $_SESSION['name'] = $row['user_name'];
               $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['user_last_name'];
               $_SESSION['idnumber'] = $row['user_id_number'];
               $_SESSION['cellnumber'] = $row['user_cell'];
               $_SESSION['email'] = $row['user_email'];
               header('Location: ../inc/profile.php');
               exit();
       }
     }

   }
}
```

Below is the HTML login form...

```
<form action="inc/login.inc.php" method="POST">
            <label>Email</label><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
            <label>Password</label><br>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password"> 
<br>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
            <p>Need An Account? Create <a href="register.php">New 
Account</a>.</p>
          </form>
```

Comment: the *exact* error is?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /var/www/html/moreki/inc/login.inc.php on line 24, this is the line 24 $_SESSION['name'] = $row['user_name'];

Comment: neither my eyes or my IDE spot any syntax errors, are you sure this is the right code?

Comment: Very sure, also confused..... Or maybe the logic is wrong???

Comment: Have you tried taking the 'exit();' out before the 'elseif' statement.

Comment: I just did still not working

Comment: I would check email and password in the first query and do away with the 'if' statements after the first 'else' statement. Less room for error.

Comment: I did that but it gives me 
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in 
    /var/www/html/moreki/inc/login.inc.php on line 19

Comment: I tested your code.has not any problem except this line        $hashedpwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `== true` and `== false`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as true so that literal comparison is redundant, and sometimes problematic due to slight mis-matches in type.

Comment: are you sure The password has been properly hashing
 on a database

Comment: tadman, I hear you but i have to learn the vanilla php before i can move to the framework

Comment: pedram, check this code, the hashing. //Hash password....
  $hashedpwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  //Insert data into the user registration data into the database....
  $register = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_last_name, user_id_number, user_cell, user_email, user_pwd) VALUES ('$name', '$lastname', '$idnumber', '$cellnumber', '$email', '$hashedpwd')";

Answer (score -1):

You don't fetch data from the database for this you can us of **function fetch_assoc().**
The function fetch_assoc() puts all the results into an associative array
plz add this line  **$row = $result->fetch_assoc();** in your code.like below

```
.
.
.
$login = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$email'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $login);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
.
.
.
```

Comment: It is true answer .Why down vote ????I simulated this code on my local host.Only he has this mistake.